# Combine tags with filters

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-1.10

Code:

```
{% firstof m.caption m.altcaption|slice:":37" %}
```

I want to choose the first of those 2 variables, then slide to 37 characters. Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by first of 2 variables?

Comment: @UrielEli `m.caption` and `m.altcaption`

Comment: @UrielEli Yeah exactly, the definition of `firstof`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Django 1.9+ you can assign the result of the `firstof` tag to a variable.

```
{% firstof m.caption m.altcaption as caption %}
{{ caption|slice:":37"}}
```

In earlier versions you could filter both arguments

```
{% firstof m.caption|slice:":37" m.altcaption|slice:":37" %}
```